# Simple Angular.js: ng-repeat not showing data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am trying to get a simple angular.js script working, just getting information from a mysql db and show them via ng-repeat. The site is just blank, no error or something like that ... so i suggest i got a logical problem here.

controller:

```html
var app = angular.module('ISPapp', []);
app.controller('artikelController', function($scope, $http) {
 
 getArtikel();
 
 function getArtikel(){
  $http.post("ajax/get_artikel.php").success(function(data){
  $scope.artikel_entrys = data;
  });
 };

});
```

Output:

```html
<table ng-controller="artikelController">

<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Artikelnr</th><th>Kit</th><th>Min Bestand</th><th>Beschreibung</th>< tr></thead>

<tbody>

<tr ng-repeat="row in artikel_entrys">
 <td>{{row.id}}</td>
 <td>{{row.artikelnr}}</td>
 <td> Test </td>
 <td>{{row.min_bestand}}</td>
 <td>{{row.beschreibung}}</td>
</tr>

</tbody> </table>
```

Index:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="ISPapp">

<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="artikelController">

<div ng-include src="app/artikel.html"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

The json object from PHP is fine.

Thanks for your help in advance!

gz
Pad

Comment: It should work..just remove `ng-controller="artikelController"` from the `table` tag, two stop controller initialization twice

Comment: Not as simple as the space in < tr> ruining it?  '</th>< tr></thead>'

Comment: ng-repeat works on an array not on an json object, that's the problem

Comment: Try adding $scope.$apply() after you fetch data

Comment: @AliSaberi is correct, try decoding the json object

Answer (score 1):

The issue was on my side , because my ng-repeat was outside of my ng-controller. Check, it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are using ng-repeat is used for an array.

To move through a JSON object you have to go other way around

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

Comment: i dont get why... Here is my Json object: [{"id":"1","artikelnr":"test","kit":"N","min_bestand":"5","beschreibung":"Das ist ein Testartikel"},{"id":"2","artikelnr":"Test2","kit":"J","min_bestand":"1","beschreibung":"Das ist der zweite Testartikel"}] --- why can i not just go through it ? in every tutorial for angular it is used this way...

Comment: For simple test, can you put the table inside the html instead of inclduing it in other html? remove atikelcontroller snd just leave it in table tag. May be because you are having a new view, the controller isnt working on this view

Comment: seems right, i tried it with the code above and it worked, i inserted it as view and it wont work!

Answer (score 0):

i tried a few other things and now it is working with this code:

Index HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>ISP Artikel</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="getArtikel">

<table>
<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Artikel Nr</th><th>Beschreibung</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="row in artikel_entrys"><td>{{row.id}}</td><td>{{ row.artikelnr }}</td><td>{{row.beschreibung}}</td></tr>
</tbody>
</tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

</div>
</body>
```

And this Javascript snippet

```html
function getArtikel($scope, $http) {
    // this is where the JSON from api.php is consumed
    $http.get('ajax/get_artikel.php').
        success(function(data) {
            // here the data from the api is assigned to a variable named users
            $scope.artikel_entrys = data;
        });
}
```

It is the same PHP Api behind that than before. Same Json Object...

I am glad that it works now but can anyone explain me what i have done wrong before? :-)